# Get printf to ignore the negative sign on values of zero

Tags: c++, printf, zero, negative-number

I'm trying to write a (mostly)* C program that sorts numerical results and eliminates duplicates. The results are stored as STRUCTS that contain a string, an integer, and 4 doubles. The doubles are what is relevant for determining if two results are duplicates.

To do this, I sprintf a string using the 4 doubles to some precision i.e.

```
    #define PRECISION 5
sprintf(hashString, "%.*lf %.*lf %.*lf %.*lf", PRECISION, result.v1, PRECISION, result.v2, PRECISION, result.v3, PRECISION, result.v4);
```

I then use this as a hashkey for a  `tr1::unordered_map<string, ResultType>`. Then the program checks to see if the hashtable already contains an entry for that key, if so, the result is a duplicate and can be discarded. Otherwise, it gets added to the hashtable.

The problem is that sometimes one of my values will be rounded to zero from, for example, -10E-9, by sprintf; As a result, the string will contain "-0.00000" rather than "0.00000". These two values will obviously generate different hashkeys, despite representing the same result.

Is there something built into sprintf or even the C language that will allow me to deal with this?  I've come up with a bit of a work around (see post below) -- but if there's something built in, I would much rather use that.

*the program is written in C because that's the language I'm most comfortable in, but I'll end up compiling with g++ in order to use the unordered_map.

I've come up with the following workaround.  But A) I'm hoping there's a builtin solution and B) I don't have a very deep understanding of atof or floating point math, so I'm not sure if the condition `if(doubleRepresentation == 0.0)` will always trip when it should.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #define PRECISION 5
    #define ACCURACY 10E-6
    double getRidOfNegZeros (double number)
    {

            char someNumAsStr[PRECISION + 3]; // +3 accounts for a possible minus sign, the leading 0 or 1, and the decimal place.
            sprintf(someNumAsStr, "%.*lf", PRECISION, number);

            double doubleRepresentation = atof(someNumAsStr);
            if((doubleRepresentation < ACCURACY) && (doubleRepresentation > -ACCURACY))
            {
                    doubleRepresentation = 0.0;
            }

            return doubleRepresentation;
    }

    int main()
    {
            printf("Enter a number: \n");
            double somenum;
            scanf("%lf",&somenum);

            printf("The new representation of double \"%.*lf\" is \"%.*lf\"\n", PRECISION, somenum, PRECISION, getRidOfNegZeros(somenum));
            return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Should probably tag with C++ too - after all, the solution probably involves the hash calculations in the tr1 library. A likely answer - write a custom hash function that calls the standard one, but tweaks the parameter before forwarding it. However, you'd probably also need a custom operator== for the hashtable to check keys with as well.

Comment: Added the C++ tag.  Although, if at all possible, I'd really like to avoid having to write a hashfunction.

Comment: It would kinda defeat the point of developing mostly-C that just exploits an occasional C++ library, I suppose.

Comment: Seems easier to generate your string representation exactly as you're doing, then handle the problematic case before using it as a hash key...  `if (strcmp(hashString, "-0.00000") == 0) strcpy(hashString, "0.00000");`... any reason this doesn't suit?

Comment: Tony,  I like the idea, especially if there's an elegant way to do that to each value within the string. Im trying my best to make the code as simple and transparent as possible - I'm worried about botching a result in one of my first scientific works.  I'll think on this, and would appreciate any suggestions on the idea as well.

Comment: If you're compiling in C++, then you tag C++, and not C.

Comment: As the author of a question you should upvote the answers that help you out in some way. If you think an answer is the correct solution, you should accept that solution as the solution by clicking the arrow accept for that solution.

Comment: Yeah -- thanks for the reminder. I was just being indecisive since there were many good answers, all of which helped me learn something.  Unfortunately, I can't upvote since I don't have enough "reputation" yet.

Comment: @TonyDelroy +1 I always do it this way. Specifically, compare the formatted value with formatted 0.0 to see if there if a redundant `-`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <string>

#define PRECISION 5
#define LIMIT 5e-6

std::string string_rep (double x) {
   char buf[32];
   double xtrunc = ((x > -LIMIT) && (x < LIMIT)) ? 0.0 : x;
   std::sprintf (buf, "%.*f", PRECISION, xtrunc);
   return std::string(buf);
}

std::string make_key (double x, double y, double z, double w) {
   std::string strx = string_rep (x);
   std::string stry = string_rep (y);
   std::string strz = string_rep (z);
   std::string strw = string_rep (w);
   return strx + " " + stry + " " + strz + " " + strw;
}
```

Comment: Seems similar to my work around -- but with an epsilon.  The epsilon is a good idea. I think with that, my solution should be robust. Anyone see any potential problems?

Comment: Edited the original question to show my workaround with an epsilon.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than sprintf()ing the doubles to a big string and using that as the key in a map, why not just put your structs into the map?  You can do this easily enough if you just write a less-than operator for your structs which considers the floating-point values you want to use as the key.  Something like this:

```
bool operator <(const MyStruct &lhs, const MyStruct &rhs)
{
    return lhs.v1 < rhs.v1 ||
        (lhs.v1 == rhs.v1 && lhs.v2 < rhs.v2); // ...
}
```

Then you can replace your `tr1::unordered_map<string, ResultType>` with `std::map<ResultType>`, and avoid the whole string printing business all together.  If you want you can add some epsilon to the comparison function so that numbers that are nearly the same are stably sorted.

Comment: +1, but re "If you want you can add some epsilon to the comparison function so that numbers that are nearly the same are stably sorted." - they'll be "stably sorted" without epsilons, but epsilons will address the requirement for them to be considered duplicates...

Comment: I'm a bit confused about this concept (or maybe just the syntax). The operator is supposed to return a boolean value to allow the map to be sorted, right?  So it would return true if the first argument was less than the second, and it would return false otherwise. What get's done for the case of equal values or duplicate results? I'm also not sure how the OR operator fits into a function's return.

Comment: @Tony: good point about the epsilons. It's non-trivial to add epsilons to a comparison function and still keep it as a partial ordering. In particular, you really want a==b and b==c to imply a==c when eliminating duplicates. If not, adding `{b,a,c}` would leave you with just `b`, but adding `{a,c,b}` would leave you with `a` and `c`.

Comment: @Maberib: Yes on both. In the case of equivalent values, you also return false. `map` will use `a<b` to check if `a` should precede `b` , and will use `b<a` to check if `a` should follow `b`. If neither `a<b` nor `b<a`, then `a` and `b` are equivalent (even when not exactly equal, eg. as happens in case-insensitive string sorting)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Much appreciated. Although I'm still missing how the OR fits into the return of the function.

Comment: If it's just a question of me needing to RTFM, some keywords to google or a link would be much appreciated :)

Comment: The OR is a typical thing in implementing less-than operators which consider multiple values.  It forms a hierarchy where v1 is the most significant part to check, then v2 is the next most, then however many others you want.  There needs to be some such logic, else which is greater, (1, 2) or (2, 1)?

Comment: Thanks for all the information guys -- I learned a lot.  I went with David's solution since it gave me inspiration for how to tweak my workaround to be robust, and that was the easiest to implement because I already had a lot of the structure of the program built around those hashkeys simply not containing "-0".

Comment: Can anyone point me to some documentation or search terms on this use of OR in returns.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that you only care about differences of 0.00001 (based on your definition of `PRECISION`), you can round the values to integers first.  Something like this may work:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SCALE 1e5 // instead of PRECISION 5
sprintf(hashString, "%d %d %d %d",
    (int)round(result.v1 * SCALE),
    (int)round(result.v2 * SCALE),
    (int)round(result.v3 * SCALE),
    (int)round(result.v4 * SCALE));
```

This also requires a bound on the magnitude of the floating-point values.  You don't want to overflow your integer values.

You can also bypass the string formatting and simply do the rounding calculations as part of a structure-level hash, as others have suggested.

Comment: Is there no negative zero for integers?

Comment: Correct.  Negative-zero is a property of IEEE floating point values (because the sign bit is completely independent of everything else, you can have positive/negative anything).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I like it, and had I setup for it originally, I think it might've been the best thing to do.  Much appreciated, and I'll keep this one in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps implement a utility function to round/snap values to positive zero. Use precision digit count similar to printf style format syntax.

```
// Prevent display of -0 values by snapping to positive zero
// \a_number original number
// \a_precisionCount number of digits of decimal precision eg. 2 for #.##, 0 for whole integer. Default 0 (whole integer number.)
// \returns number rounded to positive zero if result would have produced -0.00 for precision.
template <class Real>
Real PosZero(const Real& a_number, const int a_precisionCount = 0)
{
    Real precisionValue = Real(0.5) * pow(Real(0.10), Real(a_precisionCount));
    if( (a_number > -abs(precisionValue)) && (a_number < abs(precisionValue)) )
    {
        return +0.0;
    }
    return a_number;
}
```

Test:

```
f32 value = -0.049f;
int precision = 4; // Test precision from param
printf("%.0f, %.2f, %.*f", PosZero(value), PosZero(value,2), precision, PosZero(value,precision));
```

Test output:

```
"0, -0.05, -0.0490"
```

This is intended to be a general solution for people wanting to avoid negative zeros in formatted strings. Not specific to the original poster's use of creating a key or hash.

Comment: For double/float instantiation fabs() should be used ?

Comment: abs() typically has a full set of overloads. std::abs() is likely preferred these days. Use fabs() if needed on your platform.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only using this for the purposes of hashing the double values, then don't bother converting them to a string—just hash the double values directly.  Any hash library worth its salt will have the ability to hash arbitrary binary blobs of data.

If for some strange reason your hash library only supports null-terminated C strings, then print out the raw bytes of the `double` value:

```
// Alias the double value as a byte array
unsigned char *d = (unsigned char *)&result.v1;
// Prefer snprintf to sprintf!
spnrintf(hashString, hashStringLength, "%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x",
         d[0], d[1], d[2], d[3], d[4], d[5], d[6], d[7]);
// ...and so on for each double value
```

This ensures that unequal values will definitely be given unequal strings.

Comment: From Q "sorts numerical results and eliminates duplicates"... seems to me it's part of the requirement that a certain precision *defines* the duplicates, and you're bypassing all that....

Comment: I think this would leave me with the same, or a bigger, problem.  I'd still have to deal with negative zeros, and I'd also have to deal with the rounding.